# Why $p$ divides a certain combination? (related to Fermat's Little Theorem)

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number, and $k$ be an integer with the following property:  $1\leq k \leq p-1$. Why does 
$$\frac{p!}{k!\cdot(p-k)!}=pj$$
for some integer $j\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: if your question is: why is it divisble by $p$?, it is because $p!$ is (divisible by $p$) and $k!$ and $(p-k)!$ are not.

Comment: So $k!$ is not divisible by what exactly? I have heard that, but I am confused with that part. Can you break the whole thing down in more steps for me?

Comment: So you have here a rational number. $p$ does not divide the denominator since it is prime and integers apperaring downstairs $k,k-1,\dots,1$, $p-k, p-k-1,\dots 1$ are less than $p$. On the other hand your fraction is an integer: it can be checked by induction since it is a sume of integers.
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle

Comment: I think I did this another way where we use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to deduce that $p\frac{(p-1)!}{f_1f_2...f_n}$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Since $\frac{p!}{k!\cdot (p-k)!}\in \mathbb{N}$, then  either $f_1f_2...f_n|p$ which is a contradiction, because $f_1f_2....f_n \neq 1$ and $f_1f_2...f_n$ does not divide p, because p is prime or $f_1f_2...f_n|(p-1)!$. Thus, we know  $f_1f_2...f_n|(p-1)$, because the other case is a contradiction. Hence, $p\frac{(f_1f_2...f_n)j}{f_1f_2...f_n}=j\cdot p\in \mathbb{N}$ for some $j\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your fraction
$$
\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}, \quad 1\le k\le p-1
$$
and you write out the factors you will see that all the factors in the denominator are smaller than $p$. And since $p$ was a prime it cannot have proper factors so you wont be able to "simplify" so that you don't have $p$ in the nominator. And if you have $p$ as a factor in the nominator so your fraction is divisible by $p$ and therefore you will be able to factorise $\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}$ as $pj$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $k < p$ and $p-k < p$,  $gcd(k!,p)=1$ and $gcd((p-k)!,p)=1$. So, there will be $p$ factor in result always.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: I don't understand my answer is downvoted... If k<p and p is prime there is no p factor in any number from 1 to k. Same thing for p-k. In this combination you divide x to y where x is divisible by p but y is coprime with p. So, result will be divisible by p.

Comment: I did not down vote your answer. I do not like to down vote anyone trying to help me with an answer. I do understand the reason now from the answer above. I appreciate you staying with the problem though and trying to help me.